# String splitting- splitting by hashtag

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, so I've tried to work my way up to reading text files. I am trying to create an object with a method that takes in a string representing a filename and returns an int which is the sum of the values. However, the text file is annoyingly separated by hashtags.

This is what the sample text file looks like:

```
3#1#8
12#9#25#10
-2#12
1#2


How do you split this?
```

Comment: `Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().flatMap(_.split("#")).flatMap(_.toIntOption).sum`

Comment: woah, what does that even do?

Comment: That code is all you need. It should work on **Scala 2.13**. If you are on **2.12** or older `toIntOption` does not exists but can be easily replaced with `map(_toInt)` if you are sure all values are numbers or with `flatMap(str => Try(str.toInt).toOption)`.

Comment: Ah, it seems i'm on scala 2.12.10. Maybe that's why.

Comment: It's not a dupe, why would you mark it as a dupe @jwvh?

Comment: `split()` returns an `Array`. Many have already asked about why an `Array` won't pretty print and how to fix it.

Comment: My bad, I see now. So just to clarify, are you supposed to use .mkstring(" ") in general to print arrays because they won't pretty print?

Comment: `.mkString()` is a popular fix. Others like `.toList` or `.toSeq`. And there are a few more esoteric solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Look:

```
scala> "A#B#C".split("#").toString // (*)
res2: String = [Ljava.lang.String;@24f3e13e
```

You can do this:

```
scala> "A#B#C".split("#").toList
res3: List[String] = List(A, B, C)
```

(*) New REPL is not calling `toString` from java.lang.Array, and show a more pleasant output, so I added it explicitly to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know that was even a problem. So every time I want to check what's going on, I'm gonna need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`split` is a Java method that returns Java `Array` which are not pretty-printed in Scala by default, instead they are printed as hashcodes. To pretty print it try

```
import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf
println(stringOf("3#1#8".split("#")))
```

which outputs

```
Array(3, 1, 8)
```